# Phantom grails portlets-plugin v0.8?

Tags: grails, groovy, portlet, liferay, grails-plugin

The [grails portlets-plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/portlets) is at `0.7`, but the [liferay portlets plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/portlets-liferay) references a mysterious version `0.8` which supports portlets within packages. The only thing I found for the portlets-plugin was the `/trunk/` and `/tags/` source in svn, both of which list the app version as 0.7.

Does anywone know where this phantom plugin version exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is definitely no version 0.8 of the portlets plugin in the public plugin repository. If you look [here](https://svn.codehaus.org/grails-plugins/grails-portlets/tags/) you can see that the latest release is 0.7 and even in the [trunk](https://svn.codehaus.org/grails-plugins/grails-portlets/trunk/PortletsGrailsPlugin.groovy), the version number is 0.7.

Try and get in touch with the author(s) of the liferay portlets plugin. If their also the author of the portlets plugin then perhaps they have a local 0.8 version which they haven't released yet.

Comment: I'm hopefully killing liferay, so keep your fingers crossed.